# How can I hide statusBar in 5 seconds in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QMainWindow 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QMainWindow):
       def __init__(self):
              super().__init__()
              self.title='Hello, world!'
              self.left=10
              self.top=10
              self.width=640
              self.height=480
              self.initUI()

       def initUI(self):
             self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
             self.setGeometry(self.left,self.top,self.width,self.height)
             self.statusBar().showMessage('In progress')
             self.show()

if __name__=='__main__':
       app=QApplication(sys.argv)
       ex=App()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hi in this code example I'm trying to hide statusBar after 5 seconds. I guess using the self.statusBar().hide() is the logical way but I didn't succeed. Could any on help me please??

Answer (score 2):

> QStatusBar::showMessage(const QString &message, int timeout = 0)
>
> Hides the normal status indications and displays the given message for the specified number of milli-seconds (timeout). If timeout is 0 (default), the message remains displayed until the clearMessage() slot is called or until the showMessage() slot is called again to change the message.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QMainWindow 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QMainWindow):
       def __init__(self):
              super().__init__()
              self.title='Hello, world!'
              self.left=10
              self.top=10
              self.width=640
              self.height=480
              self.initUI()

       def initUI(self):
             self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
             self.setGeometry(self.left,self.top,self.width,self.height)
             self.statusBar().showMessage('In progress', 5000)                  # <<<---
             self.show()

if __name__=='__main__':
       app=QApplication(sys.argv)
       ex=App()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

**Update**

> I want to hide the statusBar after 5 seconds.

---

> void QTimer::singleShot(int msec, const QObject *receiver, const char *member)
>
> This static function calls a slot after a given time interval.
>
> It is very convenient to use this function because you do not need to bother with a timerEvent or create a local QTimer object.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QStatusBar 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title='Hello, world!'
        self.setStyleSheet('background: #ff0;')
        self.left=10
        self.top=10
        self.width=640
        self.height=480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left,self.top,self.width,self.height)
#        self.statusBar().showMessage('In progress', 5000)                  
        
        self.main_statusbar = QStatusBar()
        self.main_statusbar.setStyleSheet('background: #f00;')
        self.main_statusbar.showMessage('In progress') 
        self.setStatusBar(self.main_statusbar)
        
        QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.main_statusbar.hide)             # <<<-----
            

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I know this but this only hides the shown message statusBar still exists. I want to hide the statusBar after 5 seconds.